# Google authentication .Net 7

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth, .net-5, .net-7.0

How do i migrate this .Net 5 code to .Net 7:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(jwt => jwt.UseGoogle(
                    clientId: "*********-**********.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                    ));
```

> "JwtBearerOptions" does not contain a definition for "UseGoogle"

The code worked in .Net 5 with Angular. Now i have migrated to React and .Net 7 and new version of Google sign in.

Comment: `"JwtBearerOptions" does not contain a definition for "UseGoogle"` The `UseGoogle()` is an extension method implemented by community, and currently it does not support .NET 7. You can find the [source code](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware/blob/master/src/Authentication.JwtBearer.Google/JwtBearerOptionsExtensions.cs#L32) and implement same extension method in .NET 7 based on it.